# How to get a list of people who G+1 my website?

Tags: google, social-sharing-buttons

I want to add a G+1 button to my website with which I would like to gather feedback.

For this to work I need to be notified each time someone G+1's and shares my website so that I can read the comment and see what other people are thinking about my page.

Is there a way to get a list of +1 posts for a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

No.

But what you can do is get more detailed information on Google Analytics. You can track your +1, Facebook likes etc. a little from there: http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/analytics/features/social-sharing.html.

To track people sharing your website, see the acquisition -> social -> trackbacks page of Google Analytics. It's not specific to Google Plus, it links to any forums etc. where people link or discuss your website.

Comment: Thanks. I want to be notified each time someone +1 and shares my website so that I can read what people think about my company and reply if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Seriously No....... you cant get the list who +1ed your site, But you will get notification when some one +1 the article on your site [In case blog]